# ImportError: cannot import name reverse_lazy

Tags: python, django

I'm very new to python and trying to run a piece of Django code on my system, but I'm running into this problem.

```
$ python manage.py runserver
Running in development mode.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 11, in <module>
    import settings
  File "/Users/Kinnovate/Desktop/fsdjango/platformsite/settings.py", line 321, in <module>
    from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy
ImportError: cannot import name reverse_lazy
```

I'm using python 2.7. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`reverse_lazy` is newer than any released version of Django.  Are you sure you have a trunk version of Django?

Comment: do i need to get another version of django?

Comment: I have no idea.  What version have you got?  You could also just stick with the methods available in the version you have.

Comment: im using
(1, 3, 1, 'final', 0)

Comment: OK, you have 1.3.1.  `reverse_lazy` will appear in 1.4, which isn't released yet.  use `reverse` instead.

Comment: after 9 years, i think the accepted answer should be updated. anyway, django latest release is 3.2.7 as of Sep 2021.

Answer (score 7):

if you're stuck with 1.3 for a while you can use something along these lines:

```
try:
    from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy
except ImportError:
    from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
    from django.utils.functional import lazy
    reverse_lazy = lambda *args, **kwargs: lazy(reverse, str)(*args, **kwargs)
```

**Update:** reverse_lazy handling variable args

Comment: this is a great polyfill/fallback for 1.3. I needed this for defining success_url from a class based view

Comment: could this be used in a custom templatetag? I'm having the same problem with a Django 1.3 app, and i need to reverse urls that have de login_required decorator.

Answer (score 4):

you can import with in new version :

```
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
```

and use :

```
reverse_lazy("accounts:list")
```